# Solr 9 with Certificate Authentication Plugin

Tags: authentication, solr, certificate, solr9

I am working on configuring certificate based authentication for Solr 9.
Below is the security.json:

```
{
  "authentication": {
  "class":"solr.CertAuthPlugin",
  "blockUnknown": true
  },
  "authorization": {
    "class": "solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "user-role": {
      "CN = ***, O = ***, OU = **, L = **, ST = **, C = **": [
        "admin"
      ]
    },
    "permissions": [
    {"name": "read", "role": "dev"},
{"name": "coll-read", "path": "/select", "role": "*"},
   {
        "name": "all",
        "role": "admin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Facing below issues, any help/pointer is appreciated.

1. Without authorization block, authentication is working with curl command but Solr UI not working.
2. With authorization block, curl command not working, getting 403. What should be the use name here, I tried with certificate subject and issue value but no luck.

Thank you,
Anjan

Without authorization block , authentication is working with curl command, With authorization block, same curl command not working, getting 403.

Answer (score 0):

Authorisation issue with curl command is fixed. There was space between attribute in user name like (CN = ***, O = ***), removed the spaces and it worked.

But still having issue with Solr UI. On hitting Solr URL, gets below error even though valid cert is passed:

The response from the server was:
HTTP 401
WWW-Authenticate: Certificate